# Magento 1.9.2 SUPEE-9652 Patch Admin image issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, patches, supee-9652

I had downloaded SUPEE-9652  patch  and applied via command prompt,
It applied successfully but,
after applied the product image does not appear in admin grid,

how ever product image shows fine on front end.
Is there a way to fix or revert patch?

I tried to flush cache, Index management but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer below here-http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/ I haven't tried it but it seems like it could solve your problem.

1> Prepare CSV file(update_missing_images.csv) with only one field: sku and upload to the root of Magento installation.
Note: This will contain the sku of those products whose images are missing at the backend.

2> Create a file: update_missing_images.php and upload to the root of magento installation and paste the following code:

```
<?php
/**
* @author      MagePsycho <info@magepsycho.com>
* @website     http://www.magepsycho.com
* @category    Export / Import
*/
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
function _log($message, $file = 'update_missing_images.log'){
Mage::log($message, null, $file);
}

function _getIndex($field) {
global $fields;
$result = array_search($field, $fields);
if($result === false){
    $result = -1;
}
return $result;
}

function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT attribute_id
            FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
        WHERE
            entity_type_id = ?
            AND attribute_code = ?";
$entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id,                      $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " .    _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
$count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
if($count > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

function _checkIfRowExists($productId, $attributeId, $value){
$tableName  = _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery');
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName($tableName) . " WHERE entity_id = ? AND attribute_id = ?  AND   value = ?";
$count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($productId, $attributeId, $value));
if($count > 0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}

function _insertRow($productId, $attributeId, $value){
$connection             = _getConnection('core_write');
$tableName              = _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery');

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (attribute_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$connection->query($sql, array($attributeId, $productId, $value));
}

function _updateMissingImages($count, $productId, $data){
$connection             = _getConnection('core_read');
$smallImageId           = _getAttributeId('small_image');
$imageId                = _getAttributeId('image');
$thumbnailId            = _getAttributeId('thumbnail');
$mediaGalleryId         = _getAttributeId('media_gallery');

//getting small, base, thumbnail images from catalog_product_entity_varchar for a product
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar') . " WHERE attribute_id IN (?, ?, ?) AND entity_id = ? AND `value` != 'no_selection'";
$rows   = $connection->fetchAll($sql, array($imageId, $smallImageId, $thumbnailId, $productId));
if(!empty($rows)){
    foreach($rows as $_image){
        //check if that images exist in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table or not
        if(!_checkIfRowExists($productId, $mediaGalleryId, $_image['value'])){
            //insert that image in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery if it doesn't exist
            _insertRow($productId, $mediaGalleryId, $_image['value']);
            /* Output / Logs */
            $missingImageUpdates = $count . '> Updated:: $productId=' . $productId . ', $image=' . $_image['value'];
            echo $missingImageUpdates.'<br />';
            _log($missingImageUpdates);
        }
    }
    $separator = str_repeat('=', 100);
    _log($separator);
    echo $separator . '<br />';
}
}
 /***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

 $messages           = array();
 $csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
 $data               = $csv->getData('update_missing_images.csv'); //path      to csv
 $fields             = array_shift($data);
 #print_r($fields); print_r($data); exit;

 $message = '<hr />';
 $count   = 1;
 foreach($data as $_data){
$sku                                    = isset($_data[_getIndex('sku')])   ? trim($_data[_getIndex('sku')]) : '';
if(_checkIfSkuExists($sku)){
    try{
        $productId = _getIdFromSku($sku);
        _updateMissingImages($count, $productId, $_data);
        $message .= $count . '> Success:: While Updating Images of Sku (' . $sku . '). <br />';

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $message .=  $count .'> Error:: While Upating Images of Sku (' . $sku . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
    }
}else{
    $message .=  $count .'> Error:: Product with Sku (' . $sku . ') does\'t exist.<br />';
}
$count++;
}
echo $message;
```

3> Open your browser and run the following url:
http://your-magento-url/update_missing_images.php

4> That’s all. Try to browse the Images tab, now you will see those missing images.

Answer (score -1):

https://magento.com/security/news/new-zend-framework-1-security-vulnerability

about fixes in patch. Please read it and try fix then.

Comment: I am using magento 1.9 and i am having issue after patch applied